# Wordpress Settings API settings not saving for some users

Tags: options, api

I created a plugin you can see here: http://wordpress.org/plugins/vegas-fullscreen-background-slider/

Some users are saying that settings aren't saving.  For me it's working fine but I'm fairly new to php and absolutely new to the settings api, so I'm just wondering if I did something wrong or incorrectly that could be leading to this?  Though ike I said, it's working just fine for me that's why I'm confused...

Here's the pastebin of my options.php: http://pastebin.com/aSgmY42r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are few remarks after skimming through your code:

- you are using options name like `id`, `title` and `global`.  You should use a prefix on these names, like `vegas_`, to avoid possible problems with other stuff using these option names.
- you should let the users know about validation problems (check out the `add_settings_error()` function)
- use `trim()` on your text fields values when you save.
- use `esc_attr()` to escape your HTML attributes.
- develope your plugin with `WP_DEBUG` activated, so you can catch any errors before you ship your plugin.

Hopefully this will bring you closer to a resolution ;-)

### Reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_error

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr

http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress